# What to log and what not to log using log4j?

Tags: java, performance, log4j

I'm newbie to logging event for java program using log4j. I would like to know what to log and what not to log inside my log file because writing to log file for everything we have done in program affects the performance. Also, sometimes we write the sensitive information to the log file, for example, database name. Thus I would like to have insight view about what we should not write and what we should write into our log file.

Comment: "Begin at the beginning," the King said, very gravely, "and go on till you come to the end: then stop." -- Lewis Carroll, Alice in Wonderland

Answer (score 0):

Avoid PCI and PII data in case your logs ever got into the wrong hands.  Basically if you wouldn't want a hacker getting a piece of information, then don't log it.